# Kubernetes Service Resource needs Deployment Resource Manifest to be applied first in order to forward traffic

Tags: kubernetes, fiware-orion

I have the following yaml manifest for the deployment of Orion NGSI Context Broker Pub/Sub mechanism:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: orion
    namespace: kostas
    labels:
        app: orion
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: orion
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: orion
        spec:
            containers:
              - name: orion
                image: fiware/orion:latest
                imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
                ports:
                 - containerPort: 1026
                args: ["-dbhost", "mongo:27017", "-logLevel", "INFO"]
```

And below is the yaml manifest for the relative Nodeport Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: orion
  namespace: kostas
spec:
  selector:
    app: orion
  clusterIP: 10.48.0.8
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 1026
    targetPort: 1026
    nodePort: 32001
```

The problem is that the service manifest must be applied after the deployment manifest in order to reach the pod.

On the other hand, if i apply the service manifest first, it cannot be mapped with the deployment when it is applied.

Any ideas about why does it happen?

For other microservices there is not such problem.

Should i include an init container field on my deployment manifest?
How should i change my deployment manifest for such a case?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "it cannot be mapped with the deployment when it is applied". Do you get a error message ?

Comment: No my service does not answer to any workload. Like it is not connected with the pods created by the deployment. But if i apply first the deployment and secondly the service all looks fine. I have to wait the pod to be running before i apply my service manifest.

Comment: It says that connection refused!

Comment: It is a weird behaviour, never happened to me before :/  Are you sure another app with selector "orion" was not already created ? I don't know tbh

Comment: This service essentially offers a REST API for CRUD operations with a mongodb. So, if i apply first the service of orion, it connects with mongo without the underlying pod. So maybe it seems that a timeout exists. But if i deploy Orion first , it is ready to make correctly the connection with mongo. So i need a way to delay the connection with mongo before the orion pod is up and running. You can think, that when i go inside the container of orion and make a curl request with localhost it does not answer again. So the problem is with the connection of Orion and Mongo db.

Comment: I think there's a feature that enables you to tell a pod to wait for another pod to be "ready" before it starts. But i'm afraid both pods have to belong to the same Deployment.  Or you could take a look at the "readinessProbe" that may help you do the same thing.